# Kendo UI - Set parameter programmatically

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, razor-pages, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
# var myVar = false; #
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Stepper()
            .Name("stepper")
            .Orientation(StepperOrientationType.Horizontal)
            .Label(true)
            .Indicator(true)
            .Steps(s =>
            {
                s.Add().Label("Step_1");
                s.Add().Label("Step_2").Selected(true);
                s.Add().Label("Step_3");
            })
        .ToClientTemplate())
</div>
```

The above sets Step_2 to be the selected one.

How do I set it programmatically?

e.g. `s.Add().Label("Step_2").Selected(myVar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing languages layers. `myVar` is Javascript and its inside a template, `Html.Kendo()...` is c#, so you CAN'T mix them. You have to change it **outside** the template.

What I would do is something like this:

```
<div id="stepper-container" data-step="#= myVar #">
```

Then after the template was rendered, I would use Javascript to change that:

```
let stepperIndex = $('#stepper-container').data('step');
$('#stepper').data('kendoStepper').select(stepperIndex);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reality check re language layers. The Kendo .Selected() wasn't accepting the "#=myProperty#" syntax like the .Name() was, e.g. .Name("stepper#=Id#") to give each one a unique name. I tried a javascript variable in desperation.

Comment: Your .select(stepperIndexindex) is equivalent to clicking the UI... Do you know how to set the value so you don't trigger the animations and validation (can't set to index 2 as it will pass index 1 from index 0)

Comment: @TDP Im not sure how to do that, in fact I never worked with that widget. A question: When you initialize the widget with the value set, it does not trigger animations ? If yes, you can try another approach. Instead of set the value with `select()`, you may try set it with [`setOptions`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/stepper/methods/setoptions), something like: `$('#stepper').data('kendoStepper').setOptions({ value: stepperIndex })`. Worth a try.

Comment: .setOptions didn't work unfortunately and I couldn't find a way of bypassing the animations. Thanks for your help though.